# social sharing with expo

Tags: facebook, react-native, expo, whatsapp

I need to know can I share photos with Facebook or Whatsapp using expo SDK? I try to do this but I can't find any solution for this. I also used the

> react-native-fbsdk

it not works and gives an error like this.`RTCFBLoginButton does not exist in UI Manager`

Anyone have a suggestion please explain to me. thanks for advance!

Answer (score 0):

react-native-fbsdk requires a link. However, Expo does not apply to Link. So you have to use ExpoKit in Expo. How to use it is located on the linked site. https://docs.expo.io/versions/v32.0.0/expokit/eject/

and For more information on sharing, please refer to the link at https://forums.expo.io/t/social-sharing/1764 below.

Please leave a comment for further questions.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. I will eject expo as the above links and I will tell you the result.